# How to run a command on startup as root (Xubuntu)?

Tags: networking, xubuntu, startup, root, execute-command

I've tried all the methods I've found on the web to achieve what I want, so this is my last hope.

Basically what I need to do is exactly shown in the following guide: 
[HOW-TO: Set up Wake-on-LAN for Ubuntu](http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Set_up_Wake-on-LAN_for_Ubuntu)

But the only difference, is that in my case I use *Windows Vista* to send to the remote machine (which is running Xubuntu 16.04.1 LTS) the *magic packet* to boot it up (but this isn't a problem).

My problem is that the command `sudo ethtool -s eth0 wol g` is not executed when the operating system starts.

So the **Wake-on** parameter on the network adapter in **ethtool** after a reboot has always a **d** value.

I have tried to follow this other guide, which uses a different method to run the command at startup, but obviously it did not work. [Ubuntu help: WakeOnLan](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan)

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve it easily?